# MySql lost table metadata after exporting the database, how to export mysql schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL for few months and created lots of tables and procedures using MySQL Workbench (8.0). I recently bought a new laptop and exported the old database and imported to the new laptop. But I lost all the metadata of tables and procedures. I need to know the create date of a table and when was it last modified. 
 But it looks to me that the metadata(information_schema) was not included with the export. 
Is there a special way to export the metadata too or to include information_schema with the data export?

Thanks for looking at my question.

UPDATE: I found that mysql schema contains all the metadata information, but I can't see that in MySQL Workbench 8.0. I found in other posts that the mysql schema is very much exists but is hidden in the Workbench. So how will I export it? Is there any harm in moving mysql schema from one server to the other?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't backup and restore the mysql schema, then data like CREATE_TIME and UPDATE_TIME are likely lost or have changed.

Backing up INFORMATION_SCHEMA doesn't make sense, since the tables are mostly views on internal system tables.

Comment: Hi Georg, Thanks for your reply. But I didn't understand what you mean by backup and restore mysql schema. I do need the  CREATE_TIME and UPDATE_TIME even if it's extra work. What should I do to have the metadata transfered across to the new(restored) database. Please suggest.